# create data stories in CKAN

Tags: plugins, storyboard, ckan

Is there a way to create user stories in CKAN. I've found Showcases but they only display static information. I've also found dashboards but they can only display datasets, not custom text.
For every dataset I'd like to have an extra tab (like with showcases) where I can display some text in combination with some graphs of one or more datasets. That way I can explain what we can see in the dataset.
I'm not able to find any plugins.
Anybody has any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [query-tool](https://github.com/ViderumGlobal/ckanext-querytool). The extension consist of a combination of three elements:

```
• Data-driven visualizations: charts, maps and tables.
• Support elements: text and images.
• Interactive elements: filters, download options, sharing options, among others.
```

These elements can be combined and arranged in different ways to provide a user-friendly experience for exploring public data.

Comment: Do you have an example of a website with the query tool?

Comment: I'm unable to install the query-tool. If I run my server after installing the query tool I get the following error message:

    ImportError: No module named functools32

Comment: Did you install the query tool requirements ?

Comment: I installed it for classic development following this manual: 
https://github.com/ViderumGlobal/ckanext-querytool#installation
They don't mention installing extra requirements

Comment: I also tried installing it for development. Then I get the following message: 
  `File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 435, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "NOT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE ckanext_querytool ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS owner...`